# Vector bundle over linear maps with fixed rank

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $V_1, V_2, W_1, W_2$ be finite dimensional vector spaces over an algebraically closed $K$ field and $r_1, r_2$ positive integers. For $i \in \{1,2\}$, let $X_i$ be the set of $K$-linear maps $W_i \to V_i$ of fixed rank $r_i$. Let $Y$ be the set of quadruples $(f_1, f_2, g, h)$ with $(f_1, f_2) \in X_1 \times X_2$ and $(g, h) \in \operatorname{Hom}_K(V_2, V_1) \times \operatorname{Hom}_K(W_2, W_1)$ such that $gf_2 = f_1h$. Let $\pi \colon Y \to X_1 \times X_2$ be the projection. We assume all spaces to carry the Zariski topology.

Then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are irreducible and for all $(f_1, f_2) \in X_1 \times X_2$, the fiber $\pi^{-1}(f_1, f_2)$ is a finite dimensional vector space of constant dimension.

I struggle to show that $\pi$ is locally trivial. I tried to choose direct complements of $\operatorname{Im}f_i$ and $\operatorname{Ker}f_i$ to get a suitable open neighborhood of $(f_1, f_2) \in X_1\times X_2$, but that didn't help...

Comment: It is better to say what are the source and target of the maps $f_i$.

Comment: That's right, sorry. I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group $G = GL(V_1) \times GL(V_2) \times GL(W_1) \times GL(W_2)$ acts naturally on $Y$ and $X = X_1 \times X_2$, the map $\pi$ is equivariant, and the action on $X$ is transitive. This implies that $\pi$ is locally trivial.

Indeed, choose a point $x_0 \in X$, let $H \subset G$ be the stabilizer of $x_0$ and let $Y_0 = \pi^{-1}(x_0)$. Then $Y_0$ is a representation of $H$. Moreover, there is a map
$$
\phi \colon G \times Y_0 \to Y,
\qquad 
(g,y) \mapsto g \cdot y.
$$
The group $H$ acts on $G \times Y_0$ via
$$
(g,y) \mapsto (g \cdot h^{-1}, h \cdot y),
$$
and the map $\phi$ is invariant for this action. Therefore it induces a map
$$
G \times^H Y_0 := (G \times Y_0)/H \to Y,
$$
and it is easy to see it is an isomorphism.

Finally, it is easy to see that the projection
$$
(G \times Y_0)/H \to G/H
$$
is a locally trivial vector bundle with fiber $Y_0$.

Comment: Thank you, but maybe exactly this is what I don't understand. Could you please give me a reference or explain it more thorughly? My experience with group actions is not that large.

Comment: I added an explanation. Is it more clear now?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!